# Where can I find a jQuery Mobile extern file for Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, annotations, google-closure-compiler

I think everything is in the title but for those who want some context I am looking for an extern file for jQuery Mobile to use Google Closure Compiler in an advanced way.

Alternatively, is there a way to generate such files in a elegant and efficient manner?

I could not find any and I am actually getting closer to manually define the functions I use but it is terribly inefficient. Help most welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there isn't one - at least nobody has ever discussed one. Nor is there an easy way to generate externs from jQuery code in general.

The main jQuery externs are currently generated from the api XML. I'm not aware that jQuery mobile has such a feed which further increases the difficulty.

Your best option is to manually write the externs.

Comment: Thanks, I am afraid you are perfectly right. I wrote really simple externs for the few functions I use and at least it does the purpose of preventing renaming... Hopefully one day!